# imageScroll js parallax Uncaught type error

Tags: jquery, parallax

I implemented imageScroll.js on my website and get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined'

The error refers to the line 233 within the file imageScroll.js which says

```
winWidth = $win.width() - this.settings.container.offset().left,
```

When I check the "this" element for the current content I get

```
console.log($(this));    
VM2442:2 [Window, jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…]


console.log(this);
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me too much.

Here is the [website](http://www.eric-schwab.de/test) where the error occurs.

I appreciate any hints or ideas how to solve this problem!

Cheers!

Eric

Comment: can you log `this.settings.container.offset()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but just get the error message with a few more information like get stack and set stack. I don't really know how to use this information.

Comment: Is there anywhere i can run the code?     ok now i am going to debug your website it might take a wile

Comment: I am sorry, I totally forgot to add the link to my website. I'll edit my post, one sec.

Comment: we have figured out that paralax image scroll does not like the touch propertiy at line 22 of myjs.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image scroll plugin for jQuery does not work properly

```
var touch = Modernizr.touch;
t = 0;

image = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder")[t].attributes[1].childNodes[0].data;t++

$('.img-holder').imageScroll({
        imageAttribute: (touch === true) ? "" + image : 'image',
        touch: touch
});
```

This almost works but then

```
this.image = this.$imageHolder.data(this.settings.imageAttribute) || this.settings.image;
```

line 187 in imageScroll plugin for jQuery

but `this.$imageHolder.data(this.settings.imageAttribute)` 
returns undefined and `this.settings.image` is used which is `null`

This is the core of the problem i have yet to figure out how to make jQuery return the string of the image-data tags on the img elements that we need

https://github.com/pederan/Parallax-ImageScroll was suggested to me by the author of the question but it would require some rework which I am not interested in helping with

EDIT:

```
var touch = Modernizr.touch; 
    t = 0; 
    image = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder");

    $('.img-holder').imageScroll({
        imageAttribute: (touch === true) ? image : 'data-image',
        touch: touch
    });
```

works perfectly without errors but the images end up being [Object object] as a source

Comment: We did alot more debuging from skype... that will not be posted here

Comment: $('.img-holder').imageScroll({
            imageAttribute: (touch === true) ? image : 'data-image', touch: touch
        });
also seems to work if `image = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder")`

Comment: pictures are still to big but oh well next time

Comment: Problem with the big pictures solved: somehow the l of html in my `<!DOCTYPE html>` disappeared... I am a bit ashamed :D But there was no error message regarding this!
Anyway, thanks for your help mjz19910!

Comment: wow something might have happened with the database... i have no clue why the L in html would be missing